# how to add array from another file as datasource in antd table

Tags: arrays, antd, array-map

i need to add an array from another js file as datasource of table in another js file is this possible.i already have an array and which is mapped , i just need to call it in another js file

contactor.js

```
import React from "react";
import Wrapper from "./style";
import { Table, Divider, Tag } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

const CatagoryMapping = (props) => {
    const {data} = props;
    const dataSource = [
        {
          key: '1',
          name: 'Mike',
          age: 32,
          address: '10 Downing Street',
        },
        {
          key: '2',
          name: 'John',
          age: 42,
          address: '10 Downing Street',
        },
      ];
      
      const columns = [
        {
          title: 'Name',
          dataIndex: 'name',
          key: 'name',
        },
        {
          title: 'Age',
          dataIndex: 'age',
          key: 'age',
        },
        {
          title: 'Address',
          dataIndex: 'address',
          key: 'address',
        },
      ];
      
      
    return(

       <Wrapper>
            <Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />;
       </Wrapper>
    );
}
export default CatagoryMapping;
```

i want to  change the above dataSource array to the array that given below (contractors) ps: already mapped the array ,

subcontractor.js

```
 const Contractors = [
        {
            id:1,
            
            image:"contractorImage.svg",
            numberofcontarcts:'24 contracts',
            location:"5 Temple Way, 
            locationImage:'location.svg',
        },
        {
            id:2,
           
            image:"contractorImage.svg",
            numberofcontarcts:'24 contracts',
            location:"5 Temple Way,
            locationImage:'location.svg',
        },
        {
            id:3,
            
            image:"contractorImage.svg",
            numberofcontarcts:'24 contracts',
            location:"5 Temple Way,
            locationImage:'location.svg',
        },
        {
            id:4,
            
            image:"contractorImage.svg",
            numberofcontarcts:'24 contracts',
            location:"5 Temple Way, 
            locationImage:'location.svg',
        },
        {
            id:5,
            name:"Zombazu",image:"contractorImage.svg",
            numberofcontarcts:'24 contracts',
            location:"5 Temple Way, 
            locationImage:'location.svg',
        },
        {
            id:6,
           
            image:"contractorImage.svg",
            numberofcontarcts:'24 contracts',
            location:"5 Temple Way
            locationImage:'location.svg',
        },
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import it as ES module.
So you need to export const in your data source file and import then:

contractors.js

```
export const Contractors = [...]
```

contractor.js

```
import { Contractors } from "./contractors";
...
<Table dataSource={Contractors} />
```

Note: better to use standard const capitalized kebab_case name: CONTRACTORS